# CouchBaseTemplate Connection issue

Tags: spring-mvc, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have the Following CouchBase Template Bean:

```
 @PostConstruct
public void initIt() throws Exception {
    if(couchbaseDisabled)
        return;
    couchbaseClient= new CouchbaseClient(
            bootstrapUris(Arrays.asList(hosts.split(","))),
            CouchbaseConstants.BUCKET,
            ""
    );
    couchbaseTemplate();
}



public void couchbaseTemplate() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Enabling CouchBase Template");
    couchbaseTemplate= new CouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClient);
    //couchbaseTemplate.
}
```

and

```
@PreDestroy
public void cleanup() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Closing couchbase connection.");
    if (couchbaseClient != null) {
        couchbaseClient.shutdown();
        couchbaseTemplate=null;
        couchbaseClient=null;
    }
}
```

While the Server is being Shut Down i am geting the Following Logs:

```
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 8, 2016 4:57:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@40c94525]) and a value of type [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@5ddaa15d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 8, 2016 4:57:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@40c94525]) and a value of type [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@3c9810ce]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 8, 2016 4:57:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@40c94525]) and a value of type [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@23776376]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 8, 2016 4:57:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@40c94525]) and a value of type [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@7322ea2a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 8, 2016 4:57:32 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8099
```

What can be Done Here?

Comment: can you confirm which versions of Spring Data Couchbase and the Couchbase SDK you are using? I'm under the impression you have `SDC 1.4.x` and also direct reference to a SDK `2.x.y` in your pom.xml.

Comment: note that these warnings from Tomcat could be ignored if you always plan on fully stopping/restarting the server, as opposed to hot redeploys.

Comment: Its :
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: wow that's quite an old one... what I find strange is the mention of `com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal` in the logs, are you sure you don't have a dependency on `com.couchbase.client`:`java-client`, even as a transitive dependency somewhere? (you could probably see it eg. in the External Dependencies listing of your IDE)

Comment: i am implementing the Template for the first time,
Just now moved to 1.4.2.RELEASE. Will revert if i face any issue.
OPen to other Suggestion

Comment: have a look at the docs, usually you shouldn't have to build the template bean, just extend `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration` and provide the few elements of configuration (bucket name, URLs, bucket password) that are needed

Comment: This also coming for 1.4.2.
Also in my POM this also Exists
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: I did that to meet some requirments!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have both SDK 1.4.x and 2.x running in your application (since you have `com.couchbase.client:java-client` in your pom).

The thread leak message comes from the later. You must have instantiated a `Cluster` somewhere (as in `com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster`).
Make sure to also clean it up at the end of the application's lifecycle by calling `cluster.disconnect()` (I guess from a `@PreDestroy` method, as you did for the CouchbaseClient).

If you also created a custom `CouchbaseEnvironment`, you have to also properly shut it down (in the same method as the Cluster cleanup) by calling `environment.shutdownAsync().toBlocking().single()`.

Make sure to use the latest version of the 2.x SDK as some older versions had bugs relative to proper thread cleanup on shutdown (see [JCBC-773](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-773) and [JVMCBC-251](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JVMCBC-251) issues).